# Get words begin with '(' - PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
hy my name is mike(mike)
hi my name is julia (julia)
martin(martin) is 27 years old.
michael (michael) and joseph(joseph) are good friens
```

I have that line which every name repeats inside parentheses. Some parentheses unified with the name and some seperated with a white space. I want all parentheses is seperated with **just 1** whitespace. Just like that.

```
hy my name is mike (mike)
hi my name is julia (julia)
martin (martin) is 27 years old.
michael (michael) and joseph (joseph) are good friens
```

I've tried

```
preg_replace('/\((\S*)\)/', ' ($1)', $string);
```

Its works great, However one little problem that i want to ask.

***Its separates parentheses names that already separated. Thus they become separated with two whitespaces***

To me this `^` regex `/^\((\S*)\)/` should have solve the problem however its gives me error. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the leading boundary.

```
\b\((\S*)\)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qF2kT5/1

PHP:

```
$string = 'hy my name is mike(mike)
hi my name is julia (julia)
martin(martin) is 27 years old.
michael (michael) and joseph(joseph) are good friens';
echo preg_replace('/\b\((\S*)\)/', ' ($1)', $string);
```

Output:

```
hy my name is mike (mike)
hi my name is julia (julia)
martin (martin) is 27 years old.
michael (michael) and joseph (joseph) are good friens
```

The `^` is for the start of a string, or line (if the `m` modifier is used).

Comment: perfect. Can you help me with that too? it does not replace after first match. I mean it returns like   `mike (mike) joseph(joseph)`. Thanks

Comment: I can't replicate that behavior, can you provide an example of that. Here's what I get, https://eval.in/531495.

Comment: a little mistake in my server. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can easily format your string with this regex `/(?<!\s)[(]/si`

> PHP code snippet.

```
$subject =
    "hy my name is mike(mike)
hi my name is julia (julia)
martin(martin) is 27 years old.
michael (michael) and joseph(joseph) are good friens";

$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\s)[(]/si', ' (', $subject);
print($result);
```

Output:

```
hy my name is mike (mike)
hi my name is julia (julia)
martin (martin) is 27 years old.
michael (michael) and joseph (joseph) are good friens
```